# Firebase A/B testing with Remote Config: when adding a new parameter, need to exclude old app versions?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

When A/B testing with Remote Config, if a new iOS version uses a new remote config parameter, will older versions automatically be excluded from the results of the experiment because they do not use that parameter in code (they do not query it, they do not provide default value)?

If not, should we use one of the following strategies to automatically exclude them, or is there a better way?

- Use app version "do not contain" and include every older iOS version.
- Create a regex that will exclude any older iOS version.
- Create a dummy activation event that is automatically triggered on every version that is using that new remote config parameter

Comment: Can you target just the version of Apps which uses the new parameter?

Comment: @SinanKadavath thanks, this is an old post, I ended up using a new activation event. Regarding your answer, I would have needed to target all subsequent versions, not just the first one. So that's probably the regex option